# Python web-scraping using Beautifulsoup: lowes stores

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping. I am asked to get a list of store number, city, state from website: https://www.lowes.com/Lowes-Stores

Below is what I have tried so far. Since the structure does not have an attribute, I am not sure how to continue my code. Please guide!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from pandas import DataFrame as df

url = "https://www.lowes.com/Lowes-Stores"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
page.encoding = 'ISO-885901'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

lowes_list = soup.find_all(class_ = "list unstyled")
for i in lowes_list[:2]:
    print(i)

example = lowes_list[0]
example_content = example.contents
example_content
```

Comment: I don't see a city on the page, only states

Comment: once we click state, it will show all cities under each state

Comment: and the store number should be for every state? or also city?

Comment: I just need to have an idea of how many stores there are for each state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've found the list elements that contain the links that you need for state store lookups in your for loop.  You will need to get the href attribute from the "a" tag inside each "li" element.

This is only the first step since you'll need to follow those links to get the store results for each state.

Since you know the structure of this state link result, you can simply do:

```
for i in lowes_list:
     list_items = i.find_all('li')
     for x in list_items:
         for link in x.find_all('a'):
             print(link['href'])
```

There are definitely more efficient ways of doing this, but the list is very small and this works.

Once you have the links for each state, you can create another request for each one to visit those store results pages. Then obtain the href attribute from those search results links on each state's page.  The

```
<a href="/store/AK-Anchorage/0289">Anchorage Lowe's</a>
```

contains the city and the store number.

Here is a full example.  I included lots of comments to illustrate the points.

You pretty much had everything up to Line 27, but you needed to follow the links for each state.  A good technique for approaching these is to test the path out in your web browser first with the dev tools open, watching the HTML so you have a good idea of where to start with the code.

This script will obtain the data you need, but doesn't provide any data presentation.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = "https://www.lowes.com/Lowes-Stores"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
page.encoding = "ISO-885901"
soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")

lowes_state_lists = soup.find_all(class_="list unstyled")

# we will store the links for each state in this array
state_stores_links = []

# now we populate the state_stores_links array by finding the href in each li tag
for ul in lowes_state_lists:
    list_items = ul.find_all("li")
    # now we have all the list items from the page, we have to extract the href
    for li in list_items:
        for link in li.find_all("a"):
            state_stores_links.append(link["href"])

# This next part is what the original question was missing, following the state links to their respective search result pages. 

# at this point we have to request a new page for each state and store the results
# you can use pandas, but an dict works too.
states_stores = {}


for link in state_stores_links:
    # splitting up the link on the / gives us the parts of the URLs.
    # by inspecting with Chrome DevTools, we can see that each state follows the same pattern (state name and state abbreviation)
    link_components = link.split("/")
    state_name = link_components[2]
    state_abbreviation = link_components[3]

    # let's use the state_abbreviation as the dict's key, and we will have a stores array that we can do reporting on
    # the type and shape of this dict is irrelevant at this point.  This example illustrates how to obtain the info you're after
    # in the end the states_stores[state_abbreviation]['stores'] array will dicts each with a store_number and a city key
    states_stores[state_abbreviation] = {"state_name": state_name, "stores": []}

    try:
        # simple error catching in case something goes wrong, since we are sending many requests.
        # our link is just the second half of the URL, so we have to craft the new one.
        new_link = "https://www.lowes.com" + link
        state_search_results = requests.get(new_link, headers=headers, timeout=5)
        stores = []
        if state_search_results.status_code == 200:
            store_directory = bs(state_search_results.content, "html.parser")
            store_directory_div = store_directory.find("div", class_="storedirectory")
            # now we get the links inside the storedirectory div
            individual_store_links = store_directory_div.find_all("a")
            # we now have all the stores for this state! Let's parse and save them into our store dict
            # the store's city is after the state's abbreviation followed by a dash, the store number is the last thing in the link
            # example: "/store/AK-Wasilla/2512"
            for store in individual_store_links:
                href = store["href"]
                try:
                    # by splitting the href which looks to be consistent throughout the site, we can get the info we need
                    split_href = href.split("/")
                    store_number = split_href[3]
                    # the store city is after the -, so we have to split that element up into its two parts and access the second part.
                    store_city = split_href[2].split("-")[1]
                    # creating our store dict
                    store_object = {"city": store_city, "store_number": store_number}
                    # adding the dict to our state's dict
                    states_stores[state_abbreviation]["stores"].append(store_object)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(
                        "Error getting store info from {0}. Exception: {1}".format(
                            split_href, e
                        )
                    )

            # let's print something so we can confirm our script is working
            print(
                "State store count for {0} is: {1}".format(
                    states_stores[state_abbreviation]["state_name"],
                    len(states_stores[state_abbreviation]["stores"]),
                )
            )
        else:
            print(
                "Error fetching: {0}, error code: {1}".format(
                    link, state_search_results.status_code
                )
            )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error fetching: {0}. Exception: {1}".format(state_abbreviation, e))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still trying to figure out how to achieve this...

Comment: I created a full example that should help illustrate the different parts needed for this. The key components were string splitting and creating lists of links, then requesting each of those links in the list.